# Google Cloud Talent Solution Exception: Google::Cloud::PermissionDeniedError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, google-cloud-platform

Using Google Cloud Talent Solution (aka Google Cloud Job Discovery), I am getting the following stack trace even though all Google API credentials are in place and enabled. Error message seems to be generic ("Permission denied")and not sure what could be wrong. Any insight is much appreciated.

====================================================================

Error message
Google::Cloud::PermissionDeniedError: 7:User not authorized to perform this action.

Sample stack trace (hide Rails)
…cloud-pubsub-0.31.0/lib/google/cloud/pubsub/
service.rb: 459:in `rescue in execute'
…cloud-pubsub-0.31.0/lib/google/cloud/pubsub/
service.rb: 455:in`execute'
…cloud-pubsub-0.31.0/lib/google/cloud/pubsub/
service.rb: 150:in `publish'
…e-cloud-pubsub-0.31.0/lib/google/cloud/pubsub/
topic.rb: 573:in`publish_batch_messages'
…e-cloud-pubsub-0.31.0/lib/google/cloud/pubsub/
topic.rb: 314:in `publish'
…emetry_job_google/lib/google_jobs/
google_jobs_event.rb:  22:in`publish_event'
…metry_careersites/app/mixins/
job_search_event_mixin.rb:  88:in `record_google_search_impressions'
…metry_careersites/app/mixins/
job_search_event_mixin.rb:  17:in`event_job_search_impressions'
…ersites/app/controllers/public_site/
jobs_controller.rb:  59:in `block (2 levels) in search'
…k-5.2.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/
mime_responds.rb: 203:in`respond_to'
…ersites/app/controllers/public_site/
jobs_controller.rb:  53:in `search'
…1/lib/action_controller/metal/
basic_implicit_render.rb:   6:in`send_action'
…ems/actionpack-5.2.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/
base.rb: 194:in `process_action'
…npack-5.2.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/
rendering.rb:  30:in`process_action'
…ctionpack-5.2.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/
callbacks.rb:  42:in `block in process_action'
…/activesupport-5.2.1.1/lib/active_support/
callbacks.rb: 109:in`block in run_callbacks'
…try_careersites/app/controllers/
eventing_controller.rb:  23:in `block in append_tracking_info_to_rails_log'
…vesupport-5.2.1.1/lib/active_support/
tagged_logging.rb:  71:in`block in tagged'
…vesupport-5.2.1.1/lib/active_support/
tagged_logging.rb:  28:in `tagged'
…vesupport-5.2.1.1/lib/active_support/
tagged_logging.rb:  71:in`tagged'
…try_careersites/app/controllers/
eventing_controller.rb:  22:in `append_tracking_info_to_rails_log'
…/activesupport-5.2.1.1/lib/active_support/
callbacks.rb: 118:in`block in run_callbacks'
…/activesupport-5.2.1.1/lib/active_support/
callbacks.rb: 136:in `run_callbacks'
…ctionpack-5.2.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/
callbacks.rb:  41:in`process_action'
…tionpack-5.2.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/
rescue.rb:  22:in `process_action'
<truncated 60 additional frames>
…2.5.0/gems/rack-timeout-0.5.1/lib/rack/timeout/
core.rb: 123:in`block in call'
…rack-timeout-0.5.1/lib/rack/timeout/support/
timeout.rb:  19:in `timeout'
…2.5.0/gems/rack-timeout-0.5.1/lib/rack/timeout/
core.rb: 122:in`call'
…k-5.2.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/
request_id.rb:  27:in `call'
…ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/
method_override.rb:  22:in`call'
…/vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/
runtime.rb:  22:in `call'
…ctive_support/cache/strategy/
local_cache_middleware.rb:  29:in`call'
…ack-5.2.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/
executor.rb:  14:in `call'
…npack-5.2.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/
static.rb: 127:in`call'
…vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/
sendfile.rb: 111:in `call'
…r/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1.1/lib/rails/
engine.rb: 524:in`call'
…/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/
configuration.rb: 225:in `call'
…/vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/
server.rb: 658:in`handle_request'
…/vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/
server.rb: 472:in `process_client'
…/vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/
server.rb: 332:in`block in run'
…or/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/
thread_pool.rb: 133:in `block in spawn_thread

Answer (score 0):

You will need to explicitly connect the service account to the Talent Solution api and then use that service account key for the auth. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/docs/before-you-begin) for details.

[image: Service account connection]